# How do I execute code after koGrid completely renders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, kogrid

I am working with kogrid.  I want to apply a tooltip to every cell in a specific column, based on the data in that column.  My problem is finding exactly when/where to place my tooltip jquery:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

The colDef that I am using is:

```
var myCol = {
    headerClass: 'koGridCentered',
    displayName: 'My Display',
    field: 'RootError',
    cellTemplate: '<div style="margin-top: 3px;" >' +
        '<div data-bind=" attr: { \'class\': \'kgCellText colt\' + $index() }">' +
            '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bind=" attr: { \'title\': $data.getProperty($parent) }, html: $data.getProperty($parent)"></a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>',
    sortable: true, resizeable: true
}
```

The data is returned from an ajax request.  I have tried placing the jquery into an axaxStop block:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

But this is called prior to kogrid rendering all of it's rows.

I have resorted to using setTimeout and simply delaying for X milliseconds and then applying the tooltip, and this works, but it feels like a hack.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }, 10);
});
```

I have also tried calling the tooltip after pushing my data into my viewmodel.

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    _this.SharedViewModel.MyCollection.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data[i]));
}
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

This ends up applying the tooltip to the first approx 7 rows and not to the remaining rows.

What I am really looking for is a way to access some kogrid event that fires when the grid has completely rendered.  I have searched for this and haven't come up with anything, so I'm asking the community.

There is one other minor issue I noticed, which is that my tooltip is hidden under the kogrid cell above it.  But this is minor and I'm hoping to solve with a z-index.

Comment: You should probably use Knockout, by which I mean you should not be using jQuery to muck with the DOM outside of a binding handler. Make a custom binding handler for your tooltip. Or maybe http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap/ will help you.

Comment: @RoyJ - thanks for the tip on knockout-bootstrap!  I had been trying to figure out the custom binding handler syntax and knockout-bootstrap implements it for me.  You should make your comment into an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Knockout, you should only interact with View elements via binding handlers. [Knockout-Bootstrap](http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap/) provides many binding handlers for Bootstrap widgets.